# Adding degree markers to a circle on a leaflet map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Please try this.
1) Click https://net-control.us/map1Rose.php
2) Right click marker no. 13 or any other... your choice.
3) Click the ‘Click here to add mileage circles’
4) For our example, select 2 in the first dialog box and 6 in the second.

This should have produced a series of 6 circles at 2 mile intervals, centered around the selected marker.

This and similar maps are often used by Amateur Radio operators to determine how far away another station is and approximately where each is in relation to the clicked marker.
What I’d like to do is add a tick mark on each circle, about 10 degrees apart from each other. This information can then be used to determine what map direction in degrees to point an antenna for best performance to the other stations.
Any one of the markers might be the station asking for the circles, so the center is always located at that marker.

I have two questions;
1) How do I do this in such a way that the tick mark is actually usable. Meaning you can read what direction it represents, 110 degrees for example or a degree sign.
2) I’ve never liked the look of the mileage markers, any recommendation on something cleaner would be appreciated.

Generally speaking this is a fair representation of how a map would look, marker spacing for example. But each map request (this one is net 2109) would look different, be in a different city or state even. And everyone chooses their own distance between circles and the number of circles they want to see. Seems to me each circle would be required to have tick marks. But maybe 10 degree marks on one circle and 30 degree on another might be best. Or some other such scheme.

Regardless of how it ends up, I’m struggling to make this work, I can’t get a simple / or | or \ or other mark to show up on the circles, let alone the degree it represents from the center.

We (Amateur Radio Emergency Services) use this kind of map to help provide communications in cooperation with our local Emergency Managers. I would really appreciate ideas or even better yet examples of how to improve what I’ve begun.

Comment: After a look at https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html , I'd try https://github.com/jieter/Leaflet-semicircle . However your question has a deeper context, since you might want to take magnetic declination into account, and also maybe map projection properties (geodesy is hard, specially if one is dealing with rhumb lines and angles of great circles)

Comment: I've made some progress. I can put a bar ( | ) on the 2 circle at the appropriate marks. But is this correct, it doesn't "feel" right.

Comment: Please try to be more specific. e.g. what does your current code look like, how does the result result look like, how you would like it to look like. Consider editing your question.

Comment: If you follow the link in the question you'll SEE exactly what I have done and of course the code is also there.

Answer (score 0):

Other than a slight tilt to 0̷ degrees which may be explained by declination. I used the same technique to put the bearings on the circles as I did to put the mileage labels in place.